# Infinite loop in Bash showing a counter and more information

Tags: bash, loops, eof, infinite

I have a script which dynamically generates another Bash script. In this heredoc script there is an infinite loop showing a counter (this works!):

```
date1=`date +%s`
while true; do
    echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
done
```

This loop is working fine if you add only this. The problem is I need to show not only the counter. More information is needed (some static data). I'll add my *not* working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/tmp/"
my_file="generatedscript.sh"

rm -rf "$dir$my_file" > /dev/null 2>&1

exec 3>"$dir$my_file"

cat >&3 <<-'EOF'
    #!/bin/bash
    date1=`date +%s`
    while true; do
        echo -ne "Info\n" # this is the damned line, if you remove it the counter works fine
        echo -ne "Time counter: $(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
    done
EOF

exec 3>&-

xterm -hold -geometry 78x25+0+0 -T "Testing" -e "bash \"$dir$my_file\"" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This shows the [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) window with a lot of lines and the *Info* line is overlapped with the "Time" word of other line. I want to show the *Info* line separately from the "Time counter" line and the counter running... and only once!

If you remove the line echo -ne "Info\n", the counter is showing OK, running and only once... How I can add another different line (echo with the information ) above this and as a fixed line without repetition? Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure why you are messing around with file descriptor 3 here; `cat > "$dir/$my_file" << 'EOF' ...` is much simpler.

Comment: `echo -ne "INFO\n"` is no different than `echo INFO`.

Comment: yes, is the same... it was because i was trying different things... unsuccessfully. And the cat > "$dir/$my_file" << 'EOF' is needed to generate a separate script from this script. Is needed... maybe is not relevant to the target of the post... anyway, do you know how to deal with the problem? thank you for your answer.

Comment: The redirection on `cat` does not affect the rest of the script; using fd 3 is just an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the INFO line out of the loop. I usually prefer to put the carriage return at the start of the line. Neither `-n` or `-e` is portable, so I usually prefer `printf` for all but the simplest uses of `echo`.

```
dir="/tmp/"
my_file="generatedscript.sh"

script="$tmp/$my_file"
cat > "$script" <<'EOF'
echo INFO
date1=$(date +%s)
while true; do
  now=$(date +%s)
  delta=$((now - date1))
  printf '\rTime counter: %s' "$(date -u --date "$delta" +%H:%M:%S)"
done
EOF
chmod +x 500 "$tmp/$my_file"
xterm -hold -geometry 78x25+0+0 -T "Testing" -e "$script" > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks.. with info line out of the loop works!... but I think your counter has seconds at left o_O I think I'll use my counter. Anyway thx for the idea!

Comment: and it crashes when secs are more than 24... xd